# Как расширить класс Seeder?

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь добавить свой класс `CustomSeeder`, который наследует `Illuminate\Database\Seeder` из папки `/database/seeds`, к примеру чтобы добавить общие для всех сидеров свойства.

```
class CustomSeeder extends Seeder {
    public $someParams;
```

и теперь нужно чтобы все классы наследовались от нового класса

```
class SomeSeeder extends CustomSeeder {
    public function run() {
```

но во время миграции выдаёт такую ошибку:
`The use statement with non-compound name 'CustomSeeder' has no effect`

Как это правильней сделать подскажите пожалуйста?

**P.S.**
**AppServiceProvider**

```
public function register() {
    $this->app->bind('CustomSeeder', '?');
}
```

**P.S.**
**database\seeds\CustomSeeder.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CustomSeeder extends Seeder {
//    public $test = 'test1';
    public function run() {
        echo 'Running seeding for ' . __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

**database\seeds\MarkSeeder.php**

```
class MarkSeeder extends CustomSeeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        echo 'Running seeding for ' . __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

**database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         $this->call(MarkSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
в результате ошибка теперь такая:

```
`Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

Class 'CustomSeeder' not found`
```

из сервис-провайдера удалил лишнее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через SeederServiceProvider добавляли?

Comment: @InDevX, как это правильно сделать? добавил в вопрос. Как там нужно указать путь с новому классу?

Comment: А зачем городить огород когда можно, создав свой собственный класс, унаследовать от него все остальные? Наследовать как обычно в PHP, не забывая про PSR и пространства имён ...

Comment: Ну, правильно командой `php artisan make:seeder SeederName` и запускать `php artisan db:seed`.. AppServiceProvider никакой не нужен. Это вспомнилось, делал сидер отдельным модулем, там понадобился `SeederServiceProvider` и была такая ошибка.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, так в результате этого "как обычно" появляется ошибка если наследовать от нового класса. Как правильно это нужно сделать с учётом PSR подскажете?

Comment: @InDevX, как наследовать от этого класса, чтобы передать другим классам свои свойства?

Comment: подскажет кто-то?

Comment: что-то по laravel вообще нет никакой поддержки

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, namespace Database\Seeds не работает

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает как указано в документации:

1. Скачиваем установщик `composer global require laravel/installer`
2. Создаем Laravel
   `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`
3. Ставим настройки в .env для связи с БД
4. Базовый Seeder:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class BaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'Running for class ' . __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

5. Два базовых DerivedSeeder1 & DerivedSeeder2 через

`php artisan make:seeder DerivedSeeder1 && php artisan make:seeder DerivedSeeder2`

6. Внутри наследуем от BaseSeeder:

```php
class DerivedSeeder1 extends BaseSeeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'Running seeding for ' . __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

```php
class DerivedSeeder2 extends BaseSeeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        echo 'Running seeding for ' . __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
        parent::run();
    }
}
```

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(DerivedSeeder1::class);
        $this->call(DerivedSeeder2::class);
    }
}
```

7. Кэшируем конфиг `php artisan config:cache`
8. Дамп автозагрузки `composer dump-autoload` на всякий случай
9. Запускаем миграции `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`
10. Результат:

[image: Результат]

11. Структура проекта как изначально созданная при установке:

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: показал также скриншот, теперь ошибка `Class 'CustomSeeder' not found`

Comment: Попробуйте пункт 8 моей инструкции, сдампите классы [автозагрузки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176194/laravel-5-db-seed-class-not-found). По вопросу «а что это делает» есть официальная [документация](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

Comment: подскажите, а что даёт эта команда?

Comment: сделал `composer dump-autoload` ничего не поменялось, ошибка та же

Comment: блин, неужели сложно подсказать в чём дело и как это правильно сделать?

Comment: У вас, видимо, проблема с нахождением файла по его названию, смотрите в composer.json, часть [autoloader -> classmap -> database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796331/696034). На крайний случай создайте новый проект по инструкции выше и сравните его с вашим (без истерики)

Comment: подскажите, получается что работает только если новый класс назвать `BaseSeeder`. Если назвать по другому, тогда не работает. Подскажите, из-за чего это? Если создать такую же миграцию в новом проекте, то работает любое название класса, а не работает только в этом проекте. Как это проверить?

Comment: Давайте не будем путать миграцию и seeder. Миграции и их названия определяются названием файла (вероятно, отсюда и проблема), но названия файла и класса отличаются, у seeder - название файла и класса одинаковы. Миграция создает структуру (БД, таблицы), seeder - засеивает созданную структуру.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109725/discussion-between-daniel-protopopov-and-word).